# MQTTnet - Can't Read Incoming Messages From Subscribed Topic (Blazor MAUI)

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, mqtt, mqttnet

I have recently been learning about MQTT technology. As a .NET developer, I am trying to use MQTTnet to integrate MQTT protocol into a new software project. MQTTnet is a .NET C# package which can be found here: [GitHub: MQTTnet](https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet).

I am using BLE devices called Beacons which publish a message to a broker every second. Using MQTTX, I have been able to easily subscribe to this topic and read this incoming data. Every second, it prints a json message like this:

```
{
  "msg": "advData",
  "gmac": "94A408B059C0",
  "obj": [
    {
      "type": 4,
      "dmac": "1EABA5B9FCE0",
      "uuid": "2686F39CBADA4658854AA62E7E5E8B8D",
      "majorID": 1,
      "minorID": 0,
      "refpower": -55,
      "rssi": -81,
      "time": "2023-02-24 22:25:29.452"
    },
    {
      "type": 4,
      "dmac": "BC5729005A4F",
      "uuid": "7777772E6B6B6D636E2E636F6D000001",
      "majorID": 4,
      "minorID": 9998,
      "refpower": -59,
      "rssi": -34,
      "time": "2023-02-24 22:25:29.452"
    }
  ]
}
```

At the moment, I am simply trying to print these incoming messages in my Blazor MAUI project. So far, I have been able to successfully connect to my broker, and successfully subscribe to the appropriate topic (I have verified these connections using console prints). However, I cannot figure out how to read these incoming payloads. The MQTTnet posts I have found here are pretty out of date, since there have been a handful of changes with MQTTnet v4. I have been searching through and following all of the MQTTnet documentation available--so far, here is my class:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Client;


namespace Beacons.Data;

public static class MQTT_Client_Subscribe
{
    public static async Task SubscribeTopic()
    {
        var mqttFactory = new MqttFactory();

        using (var mqttClient = mqttFactory.CreateMqttClient())
        {
            var mqttClientOptions = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder().WithClientId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).WithTcpServer("mqtt.ip.address", 1883).WithCredentials("user", "password").Build();

            mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += e =>
            {
                //e.ApplicationMessage.ContentType = "application/json";
                Debug.WriteLine("Received application message:");
                e.DumpToConsole();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptions, CancellationToken.None);

            var mqttSubscribeOptions = mqttFactory.CreateSubscribeOptionsBuilder()
                .WithTopicFilter(
                    f =>
                    {
                        f.WithTopic("beacon/publish");
                    })
                .Build();

            var response = await mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(mqttSubscribeOptions, CancellationToken.None);

            Debug.WriteLine("MQTT client subscribed to topic.");
            //response.DumpToConsole();
        }
    }
}
```

I call this class on a Razor page in my `protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()`. I can see that the broker connection and topic subscribe are successful. I believe the `mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync` code is supposed to be the handler for incoming packets. This method appears to be one of the major changes with MQTTnet v4, and I can't find any examples or further documentation on how to use it. The `Debug.WriteLine()` and `e.DumpToConsole()` in this method are never printed to my console.

Any help with how to access & print this constant stream of incoming json data to my subscribed topic would be very helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are disposing of your MQTT client immediately after subscribing. You never wait for any messages to be sent. In contrast to that, you are `await`ing the end of the `Connect` and `Subscribe` methods, which is why they work.

To get the actual messages, you need to either store your client in a field (without disposing it, so no using statement), or you need to prevent the method from ending, before a message is received. For testing a simple `Console.ReadLine()` or a `Task.Delay(10000)` should work, for production you probably need a slightly more sophisticated way to keep your client from ending the connection.

Comment: Thanks! The using statement was messing me up... removing that allowed me to view/print the subscribed topic messages.